# Libgdx: Java still running when catch an exception

Tags: java, exception, libgdx

I have a curious problem, when I throw an intentional **exception** `(throw RuntimeException())` LwjglApplication **catch** the exception but the java process is still running.

This problem is easy to resolve when you use an IDE like Eclipse. But when you run the game without eclipse and the game catches an exception, the java process is still running and consumes pc resources.

I don't know what happened.

Regards.

Comment: Thats how is supposed to work. When you catch an exception, you tell the program to keep running because you will handle that exception.

Comment: If you want the program to terminate instead then do it explicitly by calling System.exit(0).

Comment: @Letstat for example:
http://pastebin.com/Wct2vutZ

Comment: @XiaoChuanYu I know that, but assumes that an exception can occur at any time.

Comment: If you want to handle that exception yourself then you need to catch that exception somewhere up the call stack. Why are you using a runtime exception in the first place?? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html

Comment: I found the solution!Libgdx when catch an exception don't destroy the Display.

http://pastebin.com/VAVNQk8S